# Jar's JDK version inside manifest does not match the build version

Tags: java, linux, jar, manifest

I have two versions of JDK installed - 16.0.1 and 11.0.11.

I switched my version to 16.0.1 using `sudo update-alternatives --config javac` command.

`javac --version` gives me `javac 16.0.1`

After that I created my jar file with `jar cf jar_filename.jar MyClass.java` and in MANIFEST.MF  the `Created-By` key has a `11.0.11 (Ubuntu)` value.

Shouldn't the version be 16.0.1? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the output of `jar --version`? You probably need to `sudo update-alternatives --config jar` too...

Comment: @ThomasKläger Yes that was the problem! Thank you very much for helping :)